Can Not Use Create View in ASP.NET Because of Foreign Key
I have been struggling with foreign key things in my project but to make my point clear, I am going to give you the official tutorial for the relationship things in ASP.NET.
I have created these two models in this page.

// Principal (parent)
public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; } = new List<Post>(); // Collection navigation containing dependents
}

// Dependent (child)
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BlogId { get; set; } // Required foreign key property
    public Blog Blog { get; set; } = null!; // Required reference navigation to principal
} 

They are our models. After creating these models in Models folder, I have created their corresponding controllers. Then, I have added this to my Context script in Data folder:
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
        .HasMany(e => e.Posts)
        .WithOne(e => e.Blog)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.BlogId)
        .IsRequired();
}

Finally, I have typed add-migration and update-database, everything worked fine. Then I have created a Blog in /Blogs/Create. It is successfully done. But when I tried to add a new Post, I have got nothing, the page is just reloaded with nothing done.I have added some breakpoints to the create function in PostsController and saw that ModelState is invalid.

\[HttpPost\]
\[ValidateAntiForgeryToken\]
public async Task\<IActionResult\> Create(\[Bind("Id,BlogId")\] Post post)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(post);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }
    ViewData["BlogId"] = new SelectList(_context.Set<Blog>(), "Id", "Id", post.BlogId);
    return View(post);

}

ModelState remains still invalid. It makes sense since we are not pushing anything to this function as a parameter from the Create.cshtml. But I don't get how I should handle this problem.
I am using .Net 8.
When I delete the ModelState check, I got no error. But I don't know if this is a solid solution.

The problem can be solved by making the Blog nullable, but in case of it shouldn't be null, the problem remains.

As you can see the navigation property is not generated in the default asp.net core MVC scaffold template as designed so and makes the ModelState invalid.
You could modify your Post model to keep the ModelState Validation :
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int BlogId { get; set; } // Required foreign key property
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Blog is required.")]
    public Blog Blog { get; set; } = new Blog(); // Required reference navigation to principal
}

This way you can make it non-nullable and keep modelstate validation.

